# Bluetooth 5.0 in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: bluetooth

I have just bought a new usb bluetooth 5.0. However, I can't turn on bluetooth in Ubuntu setting. But the old one which is a bluetooth 4.0 usb can work properly. The manufacturer claimed that it is plug and play and compatible with Linux. My OS is Ubuntu 20.04. Anyone can help?

Output of lsusb with no bluetooth usb:

```
   Bus 002 Device 010: ID 2109:0812 VIA Labs, Inc. VL812 Hub
   Bus 002 Device 016: ID 0781:558c SanDisk Corp. 4-Port USB 3.0 Hub
   Bus 002 Device 008: ID 2109:0812 VIA Labs, Inc. VL812 Hub
   Bus 002 Device 015: ID 0781:5583 SanDisk Corp. Ultra Fit
   Bus 002 Device 006: ID 0bda:0411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 4-Port USB 3.0 Hub
   Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:0411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 4-Port USB 3.0 Hub
   Bus 002 Device 007: ID 0bc2:5031 Seagate RSS LLC FreeAgent GoFlex USB 3.0
   Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0bda:0411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 4-Port USB 3.0 Hub
   Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:0411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 4-Port USB 3.0 Hub
   Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
   Bus 001 Device 009: ID 24ae:2010 RAPOO Rapoo 2.4G Wireless Device
   Bus 001 Device 010: ID 2109:2812 VIA Labs, Inc. VL812 Hub
   Bus 001 Device 007: ID 2109:2812 VIA Labs, Inc. VL812 Hub
   Bus 001 Device 018: ID 2357:0115 TP-Link 802.11ac NIC
   Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0bda:5411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 4-Port USB 2.0 Hub
   Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:5411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 4-Port USB 2.0 Hub
   Bus 001 Device 021: ID 1058:25a1 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. Elements
   Bus 001 Device 020: ID 2109:2812 VIA Labs, Inc. VL812 Hub
   Bus 001 Device 019: ID 2109:2812 VIA Labs, Inc. VL812 Hub
   Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:5411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 4-Port USB 2.0 Hub
   Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:5411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 4-Port USB 2.0 Hub
   Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Output of lsusb with bluetooth 5.0 usb (which doesn't work):

```
   Bus 002 Device 010: ID 2109:0812 VIA Labs, Inc. VL812 Hub
   Bus 002 Device 016: ID 0781:558c SanDisk Corp. 4-Port USB 3.0 Hub
   Bus 002 Device 008: ID 2109:0812 VIA Labs, Inc. VL812 Hub
   Bus 002 Device 015: ID 0781:5583 SanDisk Corp. Ultra Fit
   Bus 002 Device 006: ID 0bda:0411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 4-Port USB 3.0 Hub
   Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:0411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 4-Port USB 3.0 Hub
   Bus 002 Device 007: ID 0bc2:5031 Seagate RSS LLC FreeAgent GoFlex USB 3.0
   Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0bda:0411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 4-Port USB 3.0 Hub
   Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:0411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 4-Port USB 3.0 Hub
   Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
   Bus 001 Device 009: ID 24ae:2010 RAPOO Rapoo 2.4G Wireless Device
   Bus 001 Device 010: ID 2109:2812 VIA Labs, Inc. VL812 Hub
   Bus 001 Device 007: ID 2109:2812 VIA Labs, Inc. VL812 Hub
   Bus 001 Device 018: ID 2357:0115 TP-Link 802.11ac NIC
   Bus 001 Device 030: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
   Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0bda:5411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 4-Port USB 2.0 Hub
   Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:5411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 4-Port USB 2.0 Hub
   Bus 001 Device 021: ID 1058:25a1 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. Elements
   Bus 001 Device 020: ID 2109:2812 VIA Labs, Inc. VL812 Hub
   Bus 001 Device 019: ID 2109:2812 VIA Labs, Inc. VL812 Hub
   Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:5411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 4-Port USB 2.0 Hub
   Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:5411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 4-Port USB 2.0 Hub
   Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Output of lsusb with bluetooth 4.0 usb (which works):

```
   Bus 002 Device 010: ID 2109:0812 VIA Labs, Inc. VL812 Hub
   Bus 002 Device 016: ID 0781:558c SanDisk Corp. 4-Port USB 3.0 Hub
   Bus 002 Device 008: ID 2109:0812 VIA Labs, Inc. VL812 Hub
   Bus 002 Device 015: ID 0781:5583 SanDisk Corp. Ultra Fit
   Bus 002 Device 006: ID 0bda:0411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 4-Port USB 3.0 Hub
   Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:0411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 4-Port USB 3.0 Hub
   Bus 002 Device 007: ID 0bc2:5031 Seagate RSS LLC FreeAgent GoFlex USB 3.0
   Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0bda:0411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 4-Port USB 3.0 Hub
   Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:0411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 4-Port USB 3.0 Hub
   Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
   Bus 001 Device 009: ID 24ae:2010 RAPOO Rapoo 2.4G Wireless Device
   Bus 001 Device 010: ID 2109:2812 VIA Labs, Inc. VL812 Hub
   Bus 001 Device 007: ID 2109:2812 VIA Labs, Inc. VL812 Hub
   Bus 001 Device 018: ID 2357:0115 TP-Link 802.11ac NIC
   Bus 001 Device 031: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
   Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0bda:5411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 4-Port USB 2.0 Hub
   Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:5411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 4-Port USB 2.0 Hub
   Bus 001 Device 021: ID 1058:25a1 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. Elements
   Bus 001 Device 020: ID 2109:2812 VIA Labs, Inc. VL812 Hub
   Bus 001 Device 019: ID 2109:2812 VIA Labs, Inc. VL812 Hub
   Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:5411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 4-Port USB 2.0 Hub
   Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:5411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 4-Port USB 2.0 Hub
   Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Which device from which manufacturer?

Comment: Thanks for reply! I contacted the vendor and was told that it does not have a brand name or manufacturer name. It is quite common here in my city for such small dongles. It is printed on the package that it's compatible with linux and there is no need to install drivers. I just wonder if there are some generic linux drivers for bluetooth 5.0.

Comment: Please enter the command `lsusb` with and without the bluetooth adapter connected, and edit your question with the two output.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Edited. Thanks!

Comment: I found this, but no luck so far. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/255509/bluetooth-pairing-on-dual-boot-of-windows-linux-mint-ubuntu-stop-having-to-p/255510#255510

Comment: What does 'hciconfig' show?

Comment: Any luck eventually?) I am having the same problem, bt5.0 doesn't work, bt4.0 works fine

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same with my bluetooth 5.0 dongle, which all of a sudden didn't work after a kernel update to kernel version 5.15 on Ubuntu 20.04.

For some reason Linux kernel 5.15 is now looking for rtl8761bu_fw.bin and rtl8761bu_config.bin.

1. Download the rtl8761b configuration and bluetooth driver files from GitHub if you don't already have them:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Realtek-OpenSource/android_hardware_realtek/rtk1395/bt/rtkbt/Firmware/BT/rtl8761b_config
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Realtek-OpenSource/android_hardware_realtek/rtk1395/bt/rtkbt/Firmware/BT/rtl8761b_fw
```

2. Move the files to the /lib/firmware/rtl_bt directory:

```
sudo mv rtl8761b_config /lib/firmware/rtl_bt/rtl8761b_config.bin
sudo mv rtl8761b_fw /lib/firmware/rtl_bt/rtl8761b_fw.bin
```

3. Rename the rtl8761b driver to rtl8761bu:

```
sudo cp /lib/firmware/rtl_bt/rtl8761b_config.bin /lib/firmware/rtl_bt/rtl8761bu_config.bin
sudo cp /lib/firmware/rtl_bt/rtl8761b_fw.bin /lib/firmware/rtl_bt/rtl8761bu_fw.bin
```

4. Reboot

Comment: Thank you, worked like a charm with a TP-Link USB Bluetooth 5.0 dongle!